# Htaccess rewrite .php to .html

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

htaccess rewrite:

So i want from this url:

```
strapgua.com/index/product.php?title=Calfskin  to   strapgua.com/index/Calfskin.html
```

Is this possible or i miss something?

the script i try and not working of course:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index/product.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it!

All you need to use in your `.htaccess` is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index/([^/]*)\.html$ /index/product.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Just make sure you clear your cache before testing it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)